# Как переместить файл в нужную папку с php?

Tags: php, php7

Нужна помощь по `php` знающих людей.Я беру с сайта картинку и ее название с полей формы `input` типом `text` и `input` типом `file`, которые пользователь загружает и вывожу при помощи `var_dump` результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне теперь перенаправлять все это с кеша, например на `сайт.ру/imguser`, когда я перенесу сайт с локального сервера на хостинг?

Answer (score -5):

***Код:***

```php
$folder = 'C:\openserver\OpenServer\domains\localhost\imguser/';
$uploadedFile = $folder. basename($_FILES['files']["name"]);



if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'],
$uploadedFile))
{
  echo 'Файл загружен';
}
else
{
  echo 'Во время загрузки файла произошла ошибка';
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавил, сработало!Всем спасибо

Comment: Код картинкой и в ответе — да вы издеваетесь.

Comment: Переписал код с изображения и правил. Увы, не разбираюсь в PHP, поправьте код, если где-то ошибся.